# A question about "nice" functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function such that $\lambda(I)=\lambda(f(I))$ for each interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$. ($\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure here.) Let us call such functions ''nice'' functions.

Can we characterize nice functions?

For example;

$f(x)=x$ is a nice function.

$f(x)=2x$ is not a nice function. More generally if $m \in \mathbb R\setminus\{-1,1\}$ then $f(x)=mx$ is not a nice function.

Every translation is a nice function.

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1; & x \in [-1,0) \\
x-1; & x \in [0,1) \\
x; & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$  is a nice function.

Further, let $\mathcal A$ be the family of nice functions. Is the following conclusion true?

$f \in \mathcal A$ iff there exists a partition $I_{\alpha}$ of $\mathbb R$ into pairwise disjoint intervals such that $f=ax+b_{\alpha}$ on $I_{\alpha}$ for $a=-1$ or $1$ and for suitable $b_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Also, every isometry of $\mathbb{R}$ is a nice function

Comment: If $p$ is a permutation of $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ (for definiteness, with $p(0)=0$ and $p(9)=9$), then $\sum_{k=-n}^\infty d_k10^{-k}\mapsto \sum_{k=-n}^\infty p(d_k)10^{-k}$ is nice but doesn't match your characterization (at least not with proper intervals)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

$$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+1 & \text{ if $x$ is rational}\\
x & \text{ otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: this is also a nice function. More generally if $A$ is a null subset of $\mathbb R$, i.e. $\lambda(A)=0$ then you can define $f(x)=\begin{cases}0 ; & x \in A \\ x ; & x \notin A \end{cases}$

Comment: If you allow point intervals, *any* function has that form (even without being nice)